# Use Notepad++ with regex to replace string (with variable filename) to different string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking to use Notepad++ to do a find and replace across a number of webpages I have.

I need to change the following code:

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=600> <PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="FILENAME.pdf"><EMBED SRC="FILENAME.pdf" HEIGHT=800 WIDTH=600> <NOEMBED> Your browser does not support embedded PDF files.</NOEMBED> </EMBED></OBJECT>
```

To this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=FILENAME.pdf">
```

Unfortunately, `FILENAME.pdf` is different in every file I have. As such, I'd like to find that original string with whatever filename it shows, then use that filename in the new string.

There are two occurrences of the filename in the original string (they will be the same) - the `value` attribute of the `param` tag (`<PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="FILENAME.pdf">`) and the `src` attribute of the `embed` tag (`<EMBED SRC="FILENAME.pdf" HEIGHT=800 WIDTH=600>`). Otherwise, the entire original string should be identical to that listed above.

I *think* this should be straightforward with regex but I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find: `<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=600> <PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="([^"]+)"><EMBED SRC="([^"]+)" HEIGHT=800 WIDTH=600>`

Replace with: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="\1">`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution that will work in Notepad++ which is what you requested.

```
Find what:  <OBJECT.*SRC="(.*)".*</OBJECT>

Replace with:  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=$1">
```

You can make the "Find what" more explicit as needed.

[http://regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) is also great place to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a regex replace to replace the first half before the file name to the desire portion, and then replace the second half of the original string following the same filename with the last few characters of the new one.

Comment: probably.. but I have no idea how to do that :D

Comment: this is a over-simplification and you may want to make it more robust. i replaced 
.*VALUE=" with <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=" 
and 
"><EMBED.* with ">
obviously it shouldn't be case sensitive and the attributes aren't always going to be perfectly in that order, but you may just luck out and they're all the same.  otherwise, you'll have to add things to make it more robust, but this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: i always go to [http://regexpal.com/](http://regexpal.com/) when i need to mess with regular expressions.

Comment: actually scratch that, you'll DEFINITELY want to make it more robust if you're doing it across many files over the whole file lol.  I'm sure the criterion will hit many unwanted places.

Answer (score 0):

Archaic solution incoming...

Replace `<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=600> <PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="` with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=`

then a 2nd replace with

`<EMBED SRC="FILENAME.pdf" HEIGHT=800 WIDTH=600> <NOEMBED> Your browser does not support embedded PDF files.</NOEMBED> </EMBED></OBJECT>` replaced with nothing.

Worked for me.

EDIT: Note: this does not need regex, just a normal find/replace in Notepad++.

Comment: That would work if it wasn't for the `<EMBED SRC="FILENAME.pdf"` segment. Unfortunately that is different in every file too.

Comment: I must be missing something. Your original post said the file names are the same, and the remainder of the string is identical - the solution above will replace everything ahead of one of the file names, leaving FILENAME.PDF"> as the end of the string you're trying to replace it with. Following the steps above in Notepad++, my final result is identical to your original post's desired string?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend couple of replaces for what you are looking for...

**Replace 1:**

```
Find What: <OBJECT.*VALUE=
Replace With: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=
```

**Replace 2:**

```
Find What: ><EMBED.*
Replace With: >
```

Hope that works for you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try following `regex` for search and replace

**Fine what :** `.*EMBED\s*SRC="([^.]*.pdf)".*`

**Replace with :** `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=\1">`

Here, `([^.]*.pdf)` will capture pdf file name in `\1` so that it can handle varible file names.

Comment: @EdCottrell ***Note:** `.*` will capture only in a line not in entire file.* OP wants to replace entire line with *meta* content. I have tested it and works fine for me.

Comment: You're right, provided that he doesn't have `. matches new line` checked.  Also, he doesn't want to replace the entire line, just the object tag.  It is very risky to assume there is nothing else on the line in any of the files in question.

Comment: @EdCottrell Ok. In such case, let OP decide what he prefers. Other ans has already been accepted. Somehow I don't like to match that much long string literally.